# Android Application Level Scope Variables

Tags: android, architecture

I understand that there is no Application Level Scope available to be able to define shared logic/data, and that each activity is essentially a stand alone application tied together by the manifest...

BUT I have a group of user access permissions that I am getting via a web service call and do not want to make this call in every activities `onCreate()`.

I am using `SharedPreferences` in the application, but since the permissions are not intended to be editable by the user, the flat file exposure on android devices feels like an insecure way to handle this.

I do need to re-request this info if the application is restarted, so I believe the least expensive would be to store it in a variable.

I am aware of IntentExtras but we are talking about a Settings "Object", not a primitive type.

right way to handle this situation?

Comment: Create a singleton , load these variables first time you want them, then have static getters

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can actually create an "Application" class that can be used to essentially create Application wide settings.

Just create a new class and extend Application, then set any class members and appropriate getter/setter methods and you can access them throughout your application.

You then need to update your manifest as follows:

```xml
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:name=".application.CustomApplication">
```

Then in any activity you can access it as follows:

```
CustomApplication app = ((CustomApplication)getApplication());
```

Comment: Does this information need to be static? or does `getApplication()` return you an already instantiated Object that lasts throughout the lifecycle?

Comment: Nope, doesnt need to be static, getApplication gets the instantiated Application object (Application class is always instantiated when the app is running)

Comment: awesome, this should work perfect, will accept after I test it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using shared preferences is fairly secure. Only advanced users with root, custom roms and hacking knowledge would be able to take a chance at it! (I'm not even sure that this would be possible).

Besides SharedPreferences, you could also implement a custom Application object and keep your permissions there.

Anyway, as a developer I think that it's much more likely to be hacked somewhere within the request I do to get the user permissions (use https, etc) and my application being decompiled.

Comment: Not worried about being decompiled, shared prefs go into an unencrypted flat file.  Not worried about someone "getting" the information, just worried about editing during the execution (adjusting permissions, etc..)

Comment: And no, I would rather design with the highest common denominator in mind, and these days you should assume that your user is rooted and has access to adb.

Comment: Then, store the data in memory (using a custom application object)